# django-allauth redirect confirm page

Tags: python, django, microsoft-graph-api

I have an app on DJango. In the login part I have implemented authentication with Microsoft using DJango allatuh. When I press the "sign in" button with microsoft, before redirecting to the microsof, it redirects me to a page where I have to press the "continue" button. I want to remove this second page so that it automatically redirects me to the microsoft page.
I have this on my "settings.py" file:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'microsoft': {
        'APP': {
            'client_id': '',
            'secret': '',
        },
        'SCOPE': ['User.Read'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'prompt': 'select_account',
        },
        'INIT_PARAMS': {
            'prompt': 'select_account',
        },
        'callback_url': 'https://myapp.test.com/accounts/microsoft/login/callback/',
    },
}
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'None'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
```

I don't know what to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code for bypass that confirmation page:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'microsoft_login' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn">
             Login with Microsoft
            </button>
</form>
```

instead of:

```
 {% provider_login_url 'microsoft' %}
```

Comment: On my html? My html is this:  {% include "socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html" with providers="microsoft" process="login" %}

Comment: Yes in your login/signup html template use the new code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `'prompt': 'select_account'`, you could use `'prompt': 'none'`

```py
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'microsoft': {
        'APP': {
            'client_id': '',
            'secret': '',
        },
        'SCOPE': ['User.Read'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'prompt': 'none',
        },
        'INIT_PARAMS': {
            'prompt': 'none',
        },
        'callback_url': 'https://myapp.test.com/accounts/microsoft/login/callback/',
    },
}
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'None'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
```

Comment: It still appears the second page

Comment: @titusala then try Tech's version. I had a similar problem and the solution I gave worked..